# How can I connect an iOS 7 device to OSX before 10.8?

Tags: ios, macos, ios7

I have a problem in that I have updated to iOS 7 on my iPad not realising that Xcode 4.6 will not communicate with it.

I am working on a iMac that cannot be upgraded to OSX 10.8 and therefore cannot load Xcode 5. I am stuck - any advice?

Comment: Buy new mac? / revert the iOS update on iPad back?to be 6.1 or whatever it was.

Comment: Been looking at rolling back the iPad to iOS6 but how easy is that? I have read I need an old backup but my iTunes has not been updated.

Comment: please have a look at this blog, might be helpful 
http://www.macworld.co.uk/ipad-iphone/news/?newsid=3469837

Comment: You can download previous iOS versions from http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=750 and use http://www.macworld.com/article/2049091/unhappy-with-ios-7-downgrade-while-you-still-can.html or http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1414 note when you select restore you can hold `cmd + press restore` and it will allow you to select a file if you have downloaded it from the first link

Comment: btw 1 more solution , (cheaper than first) u can buy new iPad with iOS 6 onboard :) , but I think to find away to get it back to iOS6 is better @Popeye could you also link how that files can be installed to the iPad device?

Comment: @Popeye Thanks so much for the tips - looked at the iclarified site and it is just iPhones. Do you know of such a site for the iPad2?

Comment: @RichardGriffiths same site http://www.iclarified.com/8500/where-to-download-ipad-firmware-files-from

Answer (score 0):

You can roll back your iOS device from a backup or you can go buy a new Mac.  But otherwise, yeah, there is no supported solution.

Answer (score -3):

Upgrade your Mac to maverick. It is free version.